# Javascript pausing timer woes... Can't calculate it

Tags: javascript, timer

I've built a series of timers that are designed to be started, paused and resumed on cue. Numbers update dynamically on my page when the timer ticks up. The issue I'm having is figuring out how to get the timer to start from where it left off before I paused it. I can get it to restart from scratch, but I unsure how to take the paused ***`Date.now()`*** value, and work it into the formula to display the correct value. It will be something stupid that I just cant figure out.

```
function ticking2(num) {

 //IF TIMER IS PAUSED CANCEL THE ANIMATION FRAME
  if (timerObjArray[num].paused == true) {

    timerObjArray[num].restartTime = Date.now();

    cancelAnimationFrame(id);

  } else if (timerObjArray[num].paused == false) {

    timerObjArray[num].initialTime = Date.now()

          if (timerObjArray[num].restartTime != 0) {


//THIS IS THE LINE WHERE I AM HAVING TROUBLE

            timerObjArray[num].milli = ((timerObjArray[num].initialTime - timerObjArray[num].initialDate) - (timerObjArray[num].initialTime - timerObjArray[num].restartTime)) / 1000;


          } else {


            timerObjArray[num].milli = ((timerObjArray[num].initialTime - timerObjArray[num].initialDate  ) / 1000);

          }

          //THIS FUNCTION TAKES THE MS VALUE AND CONVERTS IT TO HH:MM:SS
          convert(num, timerObjArray[num].milli * 1000);


    id = requestAnimationFrame(function() {

      ticking2(num);

    });

    }

}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is this a stopwatch (counts up) or  a timer that counts down?

Comment: What library are you using? This isn't plain javascript.

Comment: Its a stopwatch that counts up. The stopwatches are objects that I create before this, and I store the various values as keys.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough information so, I made a simple implementation. You can look at this to help determine what you're missing. You're welcome to use it.

[Timer fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/N_Ate/L1m61jzt/)

**Utility:**

```
var timer = (function() {
    let _timers = {};

    let pub = {
        start : function(id) {
            if(!_timers[id]) _timers[id] = {on:true, intervals:[{start:new Date()}] };
            else if(_timers[id].on) throw 'timer is already started: ' + id;
            else {
                _timers[id].on = true;
                _timers[id].intervals.push({start:new Date()});
            }
        },
        stop : function(id) {
            if(!_timers[id]) throw 'timer does not exist, cannot be stopped: ' + id;
            else if(!_timers[id].on) throw 'timer is already stopped: ' + id;
            else {
                _timers[id].on = false;
                let interval = _timers[id].intervals[_timers[id].intervals.length -1];
                interval.stop = new Date();
                interval.total = interval.stop - interval.start;
            }
        },
        read : function(id) {
            if(!_timers[id]) throw 'timer does not exist, cannot be read: ' + id;
            let total = 0;
            for(let i=0; i<_timers[id].intervals.length; i++) {
                if(_timers[id].intervals[i].total) total += _timers[id].intervals[i].total;
                else total += (new Date()) - _timers[id].intervals[i].start;
            }
            return { intervals:_timers[id].intervals, total: total };
        },
        delete: function(id) {
            if(!_timers[id]) throw 'timer does not exist, cannot be deleted: ' + id;
            delete _timers[id];
        }
    };
    return pub; 
})();
```

**Example usage:**

```
$('.start').on('click', function(){
    timer.start(123);
});
$('.stop').on('click', function(){
    timer.stop(123);
});
$('.clear').on('click', function(){
    timer.delete(123);
    $('input').val('');
});
setInterval(function(){
    let result = null;
    try//obviously not a great pattern
    {
    result = timer.read(123);
    } catch(ex){}
    if(result) {
        $('input').val(result.total);
    }
}, 35);
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks for that, i'll pick it apart and see if that can help me solve the issue that I am having. :-)